# Creating a FileReader with a FileDescriptor what for?

Tags: java, io, filereader

From the official [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader%28java.lang.String%29):

Do you know any real case where the following constructor would be actually useful?
    FileReader

```
public FileReader(FileDescriptor fd)

Creates a new FileReader, given the FileDescriptor to read from.

Parameters:
    fd - the FileDescriptor to read from
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two uses:

1. Access to the standard streams, e.g.

   ```
   FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(FileDescriptor.out);`
   ```
2. Access to the same file of an existing stream, e.g.

   ```
   FileInputStream is= … ;
   FileReader r=new FileReader(is.getFD());
   ```

   This works even with having reading and writing streams on a file at the same time. You can also create streams or readers/writers to an existing `RandomAccessFile`. Unfortunately, `FileReader` and `FileWriter` lack the `getFD()` method which the other classes have.

Comment: What can I do then with the FileDescriptor?